# Finding open contiguous blocks of time for every day of a month, fast

Tags: php, language-agnostic, time, flood-fill

I am working on a booking availability system for a group of several venues, and am having a hard time generating the availability of time blocks for days in a given month. This is happening server-side in PHP, but the concept itself is language agnostic -- I could be doing this in JS or anything else.

Given a venue_id, month, and year (6/2012 for example), I have a list of all events occurring in that range at that venue, represented as unix timestamps `start` and `end`. This data comes from the database. I need to establish what, if any, contiguous block of time of a minimum length (different per venue) exist on each day.

For example, on 6/1 I have an event between 2:00pm and 7:00pm. The minimum time is 5 hours, so there's a block open there from 9am - 2pm and another between 7pm and 12pm. This would continue for the 2nd, 3rd, etc... every day of June. Some (most) of the days have nothing happening at all, some have 1 - 3 events.

The solution I came up with works, but it also takes waaaay too long to generate the data. Basically, I loop every day of the month and create an array of timestamps for each 15 minutes of that day. Then, I loop the time spans of events from that day by 15 minutes, marking any "taken" timeslot as false. Remaining, I have an array that contains timestamp of free time vs. taken time:

```
//one day's array after processing through loops (not real timestamps)
array(
  12345678=>12345678,   // <--- avail
  12345878=>12345878,
  12346078=>12346078,
  12346278=>false,      // <--- not avail
  12346478=>false,
  12346678=>false,
  12346878=>false,
  12347078=>12347078,   // <--- avail
  12347278=>12347278
)
```

Now I would need to loop THIS array to find continuous time blocks, then check to see if they are long enough (each venue has a minimum), and if so then establish the descriptive text for their start and end (i.e. 9am - 2pm). WHEW! By the time all this looping is done, the user has grown bored and wandered off to Youtube to watch videos of puppies; it takes ages to so examine 30 or so days.

**Is there a faster way to solve this issue?** To summarize the problem, given time ranges *t1* and *t2* on day *d*, how can I determine the remaining time left in *d* that is longer than the minimum time block *m*.

This data is assembled on demand via AJAX as the user moves between calendar months. Results are cached per-page-load, so if the user goes to July a second time, the data that was generated the first time would be reused.

Any other details that would help, let me know.

---

**Edits**

Per request, the database structure (or the part that is relevant here)

```
*events*
id        (bigint)
title     (varchar)

*event_times*
id        (bigint)
event_id  (bigint)
venue_id  (bigint)
start     (bigint)
end       (bigint)

*venues*
id        (bigint)
name      (varchar)
min_block (int)
min_start (varchar)
max_start (varchar)
```

Events always start on the 15 -- :00, :15, :30, :45

Data dump of some of the actual time stamps: http://pastebin.com/k1PRkj44

Comment: Hey Chris, just to clarify: You say you're working on a booking system, so am I correct to assume all the bookings are stored in a database? Or is this some kind of thing which just needs to run once with a big set of data and produce a timetable on a one-off basis?

Comment: All data is coming from the database -- given the venue_id, month, and year, I query for that data first thing. Edited question to clarify that.

Comment: Okay, do you have control over the database? If not what fields are available to you, most importantly how are the current bookings stored?

Comment: I have complete control, will edit to include db structure (but I am not seeing where you're going with that)

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to know if there were any constraints coming from the database really if you were working with an existing one you couldn't change around.. Maybe still useful to add to the question though.

Comment: No problem, hope to reach a solution! Posted the structure. Events are one-to-many -- there may be one event with several event times, each event time may be at a different venue.

Comment: Sorry, I have been thinking about it, but I need to go to bed because I have an exam in the morning. Hope to come back and answer tomorrow, or at least see someone else has.

Comment: What is `min_start` and `max_start` used for?

Comment: The earliest an event may start and the latest an event may start. Is a string time, like "9:00am"

Comment: @Chris another question, could you explain for id 4839 and 4840, why `end < start`? :)

Comment: Userland nonsense, probably. Or testing data -- that comes from my development copy of the database, so I it isn't impossible that there is some unnatural data in there. I'll clean it up and repost a dump.

Comment: Should events start and end on the same day, or could an event happen across midnight?

Comment: An event can happen across midnight, but the max_start value does dictate the latest it can *start*. Latest event end point would probably be 2am, but it isn't as though they want to advertise or encourage being there that late, know what I mean? They don't have a hard "no later than" limit. Not very scientific :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you in the right direction (I hope). It iterates over the database records that fall within a period (e.g. one month).

From that set it will find the "gaps" between the bookings and fill an array (with date as key).

```
$days = array();

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT
    DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(start)) AS sdate,
    GROUP_CONCAT(HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(start)),",", MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(start)) ORDER BY start ASC SEPARATOR ",") AS from_hours,
    GROUP_CONCAT(HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(end)), ",", MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(end)) ORDER BY start ASC SEPARATOR ",") AS to_hours
    FROM event_time
    WHERE start >= ? AND end < ? AND start < end
    GROUP BY sdate
    ORDER BY sdate');

$stmt->execute(array($from, $to));
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    // from and to are formatted as: [hh,mm,hh,mm,hh,mm,...]
    $from = explode(',', $row['from_hours']);
    $to = explode(',', $row['to_hours']);

    // skew the two arrays:
    // - add 00:00 in the front of $to
    // - add 23:59 at the back of $from
    array_unshift($to, 0, 0);
    array_push($from, 23, 59);

    for ($i = 0, $n = count($from); $i != $n; $i += 2) {
        // create time values
        $start = new DateTime("{$to[$i]}:{$to[$i+1]}");
        $end = new DateTime("{$from[$i]}:{$from[$i+1]}");

        // calculate difference
        $diff = $start->diff($end);
        // difference must be positive and at least 5 hours apart (depending on venue)
        if (!$diff->invert && $diff->h >= 5) {
            $days[$row['sdate']][] = array($start->format('H:i'), $end->format('H:i'));
        }
    }
}
```

At the end, $days will contain:

```
[2012-06-30] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 00:00
                [1] => 05:30
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 11:30
                [1] => 23:59
            )

    )
```

There are a few variables that you should change to make your calculations:

1. minimum time (e.g. from how early in the morning)
2. maximum time (e.g. until how late at night)
3. minimum booking time (depending on venue)

Also, keys that are missing in the resulting array are available for the whole day, so you should prime the `$days` array before you start the loop with all the days within the period you're querying.

Let me know if that helped you :)

Comment: With some modifications, it is working. However, it does not deal well with event times that wrap over to the next day (event ends at 1am). I am working with this code to see if I can surmount that, thanks!

Comment: This is coming together, I will use something very similar to your code as a final solution. Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of available times.  Each entry has a start time and an end time.  Start with one entry that runs from the beginning to the end of time.  Read used times from the database.  If one falls at the start or end of an existing entry, shorten it appropriately.  If it falls in the middle, you've got to shorten one and add a new one (to cover the same time but with a gap in the middle).  This gets you away from having to look at 15 minute slots on hours-long events.  And it'll still work if your slots become 5 minutes instead of 15.

Once you've read the DB, you have all the free periods in one chronological list.  You might want to put them in a separate list sorted by size, as well.

A linked list might be the most logical choice, as you'll be accessing it mostly sequentially.  It allows for quick adds and removes.  An array of some sort ought to be slower, but arrays are very fast these days and would also allow binary searches.  For really heavy usage, some sort of tree-based (for sorted sequential access) dictionary or map would give you the best of both worlds (fast adds and removes *and* random access).  I think in this case *I*'d go with some sort of array.

This is a bit of work, but it could give you some real speed.